# Access to object key values via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, object

This is my object structure encoded in json format:

```
[
{"playerid":"1","score":"10"},
{"playerid":"2","score":"40"},
{"playerid":"3","score":"20"},
{"playerid":"4","score":"9"},
{"playerid":"5","score":"20"}
]
```

How can I access to each values with javascript?

Maybe if I want to get all the key values like a simple array list format:

```
playerid = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

score = ["10","40","20","9","20"]
```

Since if I apply a `console.log(data)` it returns all the data correctly fetched. But if I try to use object notation for access to a specific value, for example by using `console.log(data.playerid)` or `console.log(data["playerid"])` it returns undefined.

Any suggestions?

Comment: console.log(data[0].playerid)

Comment: you should specify index for the item you want to access. you can access items like this data[0].palyer_playerid it gives you 0th index value.

Comment: This is an Array. You should specify which element of array you want to get.
data[0].playerid data[0].score

Comment: I know that :) I didn't specified data[0].playerid and data[0].score but of course also those notations return undefined.

Comment: Then parse it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the data and access to the array element using index:
`JSON.parse(data)[0].playerid`

to see all players:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(data);

for(int i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
   console.log(parsed[i].playerid);
   console.log(parsed[i].score);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the simpler way for access to my data object. The for loop is quite short, so it's perfect for my case!

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you are using JSON encoded data.

Just simply decode it with JSON.parse(). And than access it as object.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `data` is the array that you have provided here, you cannot access `console.log(data.playerid)` because this array does not have any `playerid` property.

You need to iterate through this array, and then extract the required values in each iteration from the objects one by one.

```js
var playersArray = [
{"playerid":"1","score":"10"},
{"playerid":"2","score":"40"},
{"playerid":"3","score":"20"},
{"playerid":"4","score":"9"},
{"playerid":"5","score":"20"}
];

var ids = [];
var scores = [];

playersArray.forEach(function( player ){
  var playerid = player.playerid;
  var score = player.score;
  
  ids.push( playerid );
  scores.push( score );
});//forEach();

console.log( ids );
console.log( scores );
```

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets `[]` which surround your data indicate that the outermost structure is an array, not an object.

Inside the array are several objects, as indicated by the `{}` curly brackets.

In order to access the inner data, you must first pick an item from the array, using a numerical index.

To select the first object from the array:

`data[0] // {playerid:"1",score:"10"}`

To access properties within that object, you can use object notation:

`data[0].playerid // "1"`

You could also loop over the items in the array to access all the objects:

```
data.forEach((item)=>{
    console.log(item);
});
```

Comment: With `data.forEach((item)=>{console.log(item);});` i get this error  `Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Try a traditional for loop: `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]);
}`

Comment: Or it sounds like you perhaps need to parse the json data first as is suggested in another answer ` var parsed = JSON.parse(data) ;`